# Script to move entire row to a new tab and then selected columns to a different doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script running on a document (I found on the forum and unfortunately I cannot remember who it was to give credit to but it works great), pulling the whole rows data into a new sheet then deleting the row from its current location;

```
function onEdit(event)
{
    // assumes source data in sheet named Schedule
    // target sheet of move to named Invoiced
    // test column with "9 - Invoiced" is col 1
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
    var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

    if(s.getName() == "AllOpps" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == 
"Outreached")
    {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("InitialOutreach");
        if(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1 == targetSheet.getMaxRows())
        {
            targetSheet.insertRowsAfter(targetSheet.getLastRow(), 5); 
            //inserts 5 rows after last used row
        }
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
        s.deleteRow(row);
    }
}
```

What I am looking for is an amendment to this and I have no idea how to make it work as my script knowledge is extremely limited, in fact, I am not even sure if it is possible but here goes.

Upon selection of "Outreached" I would like that row to do 2 things, firstly for the whole row to be copied across to the InitialOutreach tab, as it does now, and at the same time column 11,12,13 and 14 to be copied into a completely different document, for ease of use I have added it in the shared sample doc as Mail. This second copy will need to be into the respectively named columns

You can find a sample sheet here. Please, note that AllOpps and Initial Outreach are in the same document and represents the initial transfer while Mail Merge tab will be the second transfer. Once again the second transfer ie. only select columns will be in a completely different document.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x_NFLXC2doWAgCWcAbxpuAh1vW-IclMZ1prN4loWdDA/edit?usp=sharing.

Once again I am not even sure running 2 different tasks on 1 trigger is even possible.

Comment: This is doable and no problems with multiple tasks on 1 trigger. I started but got diverted so your test sheet has some extra test data.. If nobody else does it first, I will attend to it later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE:** This reply has been modified from previous versions, to deal with various changes and problems as reported by the OP.

The code below should do what you need. Note carefully the changed function name `myOnEdit` which also appears in the `onOpen` event, where it is named as an "installable" trigger. See later notes on reason for this.

```
 function onOpen() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myOnEdit')
   .onEdit()
   .create();
}

function myOnEdit(event)
{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
    var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

    if(s.getName() == "AllOpps" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == "Outreached")
    {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();

        // first copy and paste the "Outreached" row in entrity
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("InitialOutreach");
        if(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1 == targetSheet.getMaxRows())
        {
            targetSheet.insertRowsAfter(targetSheet.getLastRow(), 5); 
            //inserts 5 rows after last used row
        } 
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1);
        var values = s.getRange(row, 11, 1, 5).getValues();   // save the values to copy to "mail Merge" 
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
        Logger.log(values);

        // Copy the required columns to "Mail Merge" spreadsheet"
        var mailMergeSS= SpreadsheetApp.openById('--copy your sheet ID here--');
        targetSheet = mailMergeSS.getSheetByName("Mail Merge");
        if(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1 == targetSheet.getMaxRows())
        {
            targetSheet.insertRowsAfter(targetSheet.getLastRow(), 5); 
            //inserts 5 rows after last used row
        }
        target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,5);
        target.setValues(values);

        s.deleteRow(row);
    }
}
```

1) Make the new target spreadsheet for the mail merge lines and make a new tag called "Mail Merge". Make

2) To find the ID of the new sheet open it and look at the URL. It should look something like this:
    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/**14NP6TUyj1xLCPjKsPdGS6fiO0Bvzv1u4696LFd3tA7I**/edit#gid=0

The ID is the emboldened bit ie `14NP6TUyj1xLCPjKsPdGS6fiO0Bvzv1u4696LFd3tA7I` in the example above,. Yours will be different, so copy and paste it so that your code line looks like:

```
var mailMergeSS= SpreadsheetApp.openById('14NP6TUyj1xLCPjKsPdGS6fiO0Bvzv1u4696LFd3tA7I');
```

To avoid this error:

> SpreadsheetApp.openById([0AjqSnE_p3nFqdDN0LWpFbjFqVDRwNmFGOV91QzZrZc])
>   [0 seconds] Execution failed: You do not have permission to perform
>   that action.

.. which arises when you try to open an external sheet, you need to use "Installable Triggers". The appropriate references are here:

[www.developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

[developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Installable triggers can be installed in 2 ways:

1. In your CopyCols sheet, go to the `script editor` and select Current
   Project Triggers. Add a new trigger with settings as follows: Choose
   which function to run:   `myOnEdit` Which runs at deployment:
   `head` Select Event Source:            `from Spreadsheet` Select
   event type:              `onEdit` Then save and restart your sheet..
2. or....In your code add this function lines:

`function onOpen() {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('myOnEdit')
    .onEdit()
    .create();
}`

Comment: Hi there,I made a small error creating the sample sheet and forgot to enter the "Last Name" column on AllOpps and InitialOutreach sheets, hence the formating error. :-( I have added it in now, however, when copying across o Mail Merge it now needs to be columns 11,12,13,14 and 15? How to go about this?

Comment: OK no worries and I will fix it - stand by.

Comment: Ok is done, just had to change value of 4 to 5 in 2 places. Test it please and let me know if good.

Comment: that now works perfectly for the formatting and multiple tasks on 1 trigger. I did try and explain in my original post that the mail merge tab is in the sample sheet for ease of use, in reality, it is in a completely different doc.                                
                                                                                                                                   I have found something like this but do not know how to implement it in your script                                   
    var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheet ID').getSheets()[0];

Comment: Ok try the above. If all works, consider to upvote and/or accept to close question off. (arrows and ticks at top left of reply).  Otherwise let me know and I'll stay with it until done!

Comment: hi, I made the alterations to the script however the second task does not work. I already had the sheet created and a tab called 'Mail Merge' but it does not copy, also the row in Opps is not deleted, I guess this is so because the second task was not completed.

Comment: I tried it here and seemed to work OK. However, its possible that there is a permission problem with the second sheet. If you are not familiar with the dev tools then this is hard to see. I will check the test sheet and see what I can.

Comment: Ok your test sheet has not been changed. Can you update the test sheet and make sure is saved with the correct ID for the new target sheet? Then I can see whats happening...

Comment: ok done. thanks for your time, I really appreciate your efforts

Comment: Can you also post a link to the new target sheet?

Comment: Ok Apologies. I have to go do stuff. This is a small issue so don't give up! Post link to new test site + link to new target sheet with "Mail Merge" sheet included. If you create the new sheet then you should have permission.

Comment: All the sheets are created and owned by me, so as far as I understand I should have permissions. Anyways, I have just created this new doc with the required "Mail Merge" sheet; https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uRHZERi11xsHO-DeM2pXu52AqXl-0-RMysvVDtzkN4Y/edit#gid=0.

Comment: I tried to run the script however it failed again on the second task. This is the last bit of the execution transcript '[18-11-13 14:00:35:400 EET] SpreadsheetApp.openById([1uRHZERi11xsHO-DeM2pXu52AqXl-0-RMysvVDtzkN4Y]) [0 seconds]
[18-11-13 14:00:35:776 EET] Execution failed: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets (line 29, file "Code") [13.784 seconds total runtime]

Comment: OK I read up on this error, which I did not get by the way???, and made a few changes that were successful with other people who got the same error. Lets give that try... Let me know how you go. I will try to test also...

Comment: I tested above and all worked. I had to create my own "mail Merge" sheet as your link was read only, but the script successfully copied the records to the new sheet. Make sure the ID in your scripts matches your target if you change the target. Read the execution transcript if problems. I installed a trigger on your test sheet, so you may have to delete and reinstall.. good luck!

Comment: Brilliant!! Taking your edited script above and then also creating an installable trigger as per your comment has done it. It works perfectly and as originally requested. I really appreciate your time on this so much. Will be a massive boost to my workflow. Thank you 100 times over!! Best J